# M1 to M2 Migration Isssue

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate Magento v1.9.5 data to Magento v2.3.5 using the following command:

bin/magento migrate:data --reset --auto /app/code/Vendor/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.5/config.xml

This fails with this error:
[ERROR]: Not mapped id key 396 found for eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id

Can anybody give me any pointers in how to resolve this?

Comment: maybe this can help : https://www.catgento.com/2020/04/13/magento-2-migration-errors-data-integrity-step/

Comment: I tried that and got the same error message. I also tried the following from another post but again got the same error message: Remove 138 attribut_id row from catalog_eav_attribute.

Remove 138 attribut_id row from catalog_product_entity_int.

Remove 138 attribut_id row from eav_entity_attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Right - I've sorted this without any apparent loss of data.

On the DESTINATION database (NOT the source database):

Remove 138 attribut_id row from catalog_eav_attribute

Remove 138 attribut_id row from eav_entity_attribute

catalog_product_entity_int was an empty table so no action required.

This generated the following error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 18 in /home/porscheshopco/testnewversion/vendor/m
agento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 492

I corrected this by modifying '/vendor/m
agento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php' as per these instructions:

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/ea9cc9f21d3634dd3695fd88f9c869d9535cb6a6

Hope this may be of use to someone else.